# Contact form without refresh

Tags: php, jquery, contact-form

I've been trying to create this form to display errors or a confirmation message without a page refresh.

I've been trying to use jQuery but with no success. My jQuery code is completely wrong and I've tried to create it far too many times now.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

HTML

```
   <form method="post" action="index.php" autocomplete="on">

        <label>Name</label>
        <input name="name" placeholder="What is your name?">

        <label>Email</label>
        <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Your email please">

        <label>Message</label>
        <textarea rows="10"name="message" placeholder="What would you like to say?"></textarea>

        <label>*What is 2+2? (Anti-spam)</label>
        <input name="human" placeholder="Type Here">

        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From: removed '; 
    $to = 'removed'; 
    $subject = 'From: removed';
    $human = $_POST['human'];

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    if ($_POST['submit']) {
        if ($name != '' && $email != '') {
            if ($human == '4') {                 
                if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
                echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
            } else { 
                echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
            } 
        } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
            echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
        }
        } else {
            echo '<p>You need to fill in all required fields!!</p>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: you need to use ajax, and prevent to submit form when `#submit` is pushed.

Comment: Where is your jQuery code?

Comment: a, where is your jquery code? b, if your jquery is wrong then start from scratch, c, there are plenty of online examples out there where you can start using it as a reference to have a good start.

Comment: Just a note, your "anti spam" would not be really effective and you might rather want to use something like reCapcha since some bots, or actually alot might be able to read your `2+2` sum.

Comment: @terry I completely scrapped my code

Comment: @unixmiah I will try you option c

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at $.post from jQuery.

You could have a form like that:

```
<form id="form">
    <label for="field">Field</label><br />
    <input name="field" id="field" placeholder="Field" />
    <span id="responseField"></span>
    <br /><br />
    <input type='submit' value='Send !'/>
</form>
```

A PHP check like that:

```
$json = array("status" => "OK", "error" => []);
if (isset($_POST['field'])) // Test if every field is here
{
    // Test if "field" is OK
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/", $_POST['field']))
    {
        $json['status'] = "NO";
        $json['error']['field'] = "Must be alphanumeric";
    }
}
else
    $json['status'] = "NO";

echo json_encode($json);
exit();
```

And a JS like that

```
$(document).on("ready", function() {
    $("#form").submit(function() {
        var url = "check.php";
        $.post(url, {field: $("#field").val()}, function(data) {
            var json = $.parseJSON(data);
            if (json.status == "OK")
                alert("Everything is OK!");
            else
                $("#responseField").html(json.error.field || "");
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

What will happen: You send the "field" value, it is checked in the PHP (here, just an alphanumeric check, do what you want). As you check the form, fill the `$json` variable. Send it after. Your JS will then check if everything went OK, else it will print your feedback in the span after the field.

For more portability, check JasonK's answer, it sends the whole form automatically, which is way better than building the object to send. He also check if the ajax request fails, which is a very good habit, my code is down to the simplest to understand how AJAX requests works.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I could. In order to achieve this you need to use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Something like the following should work, but I haven't tested it:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    var formData = $(this).serialize(); //Get the form data (input)

    //Post with AJAX
    $.post("post-contact.php", formData)
    .done(function(data) {
        alert('Succes!')
    })
    .fail(function(data) {
        alert('Failed!')
    }); 

    return false; //Prevent form from being submitted (same as e.preventDefault())
});
```

I hope this helps you out, you should read the docs for more information.

Comment: you need to put your form validation code or confirmation code after the $('form').submit or in between.

Comment: Thank you, it didn't work but the code advice is really helpful

Comment: @Wiseguy That´s weird, this is the exact answer to your question which should also work :p